# Trying to make my program change an int value from 0 to 1

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int profileClearanceLevel = 0;

void clearanceLevel (int **a) {
    *a = &profileClearanceLevel;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Greetings and welcome to the Aperture Science Enrichment Center Employee Database." << endl;
    string enterToContinue = "Press enter to continue.";
    cout << enterToContinue << endl;
    cin.get();
    cout << "Please input ID: " << flush;
    int identificationNumber;
    cin >> identificationNumber;
    while (identificationNumber < 1) {
        cout << "Specified profile not found. Please try again." << endl;
        cout << enterToContinue << endl;
        cin.get();
        cin.get();
        cout << "Please input ID: " << flush;
        cin >> identificationNumber;
    }
    while (identificationNumber > 1) {
        cout << "Specified profile not found. Please try again." << endl;
        cout << enterToContinue << endl;
        cin.get();
        cin.get();
        cout << "Please input ID: " << flush;
        cin >> identificationNumber;
    }
    clearanceLevel (&profileClearanceLevel);
    int *profileClearanceLevel = 0;
    if (identificationNumber == 1) {
        cout << "Please input your password: " << flush;
        int profilePassword;
        cin >> profilePassword;
        while (profilePassword != 2356) {
            cout << "Incorrect password. Please try again." << endl;
            cout << enterToContinue << endl;
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
            cout << "Please input your password: " << flush;
            cin >> profilePassword;
        }
        if (profilePassword == 2356) {
            int employeeNumber = 1;
            int *profileClearanceLevel = 1;
            cout << "Welcome, Employee #" << employeeNumber << endl;
            cout << "Clearance level: " << profileClearanceLevel << endl;
            cout << enterToContinue << endl;
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
        }
    }
    if (*profileClearanceLevel == 1) {
        cout << "it worked" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
00:12:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Menu ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Menu.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Menu.d" -MT"src/Menu.o" -o "src/Menu.o" "../src/Menu.cpp"
../src/Menu.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../src/Menu.cpp:35:44: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void clearanceLevel(int**)'
      clearanceLevel (&profileClearanceLevel);
                                            ^
../src/Menu.cpp:51:37: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
        int *profileClearanceLevel = 1;
                                     ^
make: *** [src/Menu.o] Error 1

00:12:59 Build Finished (took 723ms)
```

I am completely new to C++ and I've only gotten to learning If and If - else. But I figured I know enough to create a kind of database menu program of sorts. I googled how to change an int value, and I came across a few posts and I tried to deal with pointers here, but I clearly have no experience in this and I have no idea what to do. Please help me fix this, I've been doing this for hours.

Comment: The compiler errors are self explanatory: passing an `int *` to a function that expects an `int **`; and attempting to assign an `int` to an `int *`. What specifically do you not understand? Although C++ has a good reputation for obscure, confusing compilation errors, this isn't the case here. Your compiler's errors are fairly simple, and tame.

Comment: I suppose I should have been more clear - I understand. But everything I can think of is not working. So I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Easify Why all of that unnecessary pointer mess?

Comment: I already said that I'm trying to change an int profileClearanceLevel from 0 to 1.

Comment: You don't need pointers for that. Try using just ints for a start. Saves fancy pointer stuff for when you are trying to do things that are actually complex.

Comment: How to fix it is very simple. Don't pass an `int *` to a function that expects an `int **`, and don't assign an `int` to a pointer to an int. Again, what exactly you do not understand?

Comment: Then what do I need to do? I want the program to change the value by itself

Comment: Get rid of the * and ** on all variables. Just never use that and write your code to work that way.

Comment: You can in fact just directly access the variable "profileClearanceLevel" to change it without any fancy code. But if you want to, write get & set functions: 
int getClearanceLevel () {
    return profileClearanceLevel;
}


void setClearanceLevel (int newLevel) {
    profileClearanceLevel = newLevel;
}

Answer (score -1):

you could just use a bool to get rid of your whole problem just display the one or the two.

Comment: this should be a comment.